# Objective-c UIDocumentInteractionController loads gray screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to preview a UIDocumentInteractionController like so:

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FLW-0032 Design Sketches" ofType:@"pdf"];

_previewItemURL = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];

UIDocumentInteractionController *documentInteractionController =[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:_previewItemURL];
                        
documentInteractionController.delegate = self;

[documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
```

And all I get is the gray screen with the file name. The file is 5.5MB

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my delegate method:

```
- (UIViewController *) documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview: (UIDocumentInteractionController *) controller {
    return self.navigationController;
}
```

I am seeing this in my console log

> [Snapshotting] Snapshotting a view (0x108c80800,
> _UIButtonBarStackView) that has not been rendered at least once requires afterScreenUpdates:YES. 2018-03-07 20:39:16.169613-0500
> SchedulingiPadApplication[417:61893] [default] Couldn't issue file
> extension for url:
> file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/23540D89-0841-4F12-A6A4-A2840D4076F4/SchedulingiPadApplication.app/FLW-0032%20Design%20Sketches.pdf
>
> ## PreviewItem

This happens when I a presenting the documentInteractionController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `NSURL fileURLWithPath:`, not `URLWithString:`.

Better yet, use `NSBundle URLForResource:withExtension:` to get the `NSURL` directly.

Comment: Tried fileURLWithPath, got this: Couldn't issue file extension for url still gray screen with file name

Comment: Tried our other solution, same thing Couldn't issue file extension for url: file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/A280CC8F-7AC7-46DB-BD47-B64C76A35F7A/SchedulingiPadApplication.app/FLW-0032%20Design%20Sketches.pdf #PreviewItem
and gray screen with file name

Comment: Are you sure the PDF file is valid? Where exactly are you seeing the message "Couldn't issue file extension for url"? Update your question with the exact and complete error message.

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: @Daij-Djan I think you meant to post your comment on the question, not my answer.

Comment: @rmaddy sorry I answered to the ops commented 'updated my question'